# Python Remainder Division Assertion Error

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to do the operation `50.0 % 0.01`, but when I assert my statement to equal true, it returns false.

Anyone know why this may be?

EDIT: I should probably also note, the values of 50.0 and 0.01 are being represented by variables. I know that I can add in `from decimal import Decimal` but that doesn't allow me to use my variables.

Comment: What does your assert statement look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by floating point imprecision.

Try: `print(50.0 % 0.01)` - you'll get something like `0.00999999999999896`.

For cases like this, it's common to assert the value to be smaller than some arbitrary number instead of trying to get the exact right answer.

See: [Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html)